# Combining data coming from multiple kafka to single kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra

I have N Kafka topic, with data and a timestamp, I need to combine them in a single topic with sorted timestamp order, where the data is sorted inside the partition. I got one way to do that.

Combine all the Kafka topic data in Cassandra(because of its fast write) with clustering order as DESCENDING, it will combine them all but the limit would be if after a timed window of accumulation of data if a data came late, it won't be sorted

Is there any other appropriate way to do that? If not then is there any chance of improvement in my solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you need Kafka to sort on timestamps. Typically this is done only at consumption time for each batch of messages.

For example, create Kafka Streams process that reads from all topics. Create a Global KTable and enable Interactive Querying.

When you query, then you sort the data on the client side, regardless of how it is ordered in the topic.

This way, you are no limited to a single, ordered partition.

---

Alternatively, I would write to something other than Cassandra (due to my lack of deep knowledge of it). For example, Couchbase or CockroachDB.

Then when you query those later, run a `SORT BY`